# Run a command line tools with arguments in AppleScript

Tags: xcode, applescript

I did the following and it works fine, I added my Command Line Tool to the Resource Folder of my project and did the following below:

`set myPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "MyComandLineTool")
            do shell script "cp " & quoted form of POSIX path of myPath & space & "/private/tmp" with administrator privileges
            set cmd to "/private/tmp/myPath -r"
            do shell script " " & cmd with administrator privileges`

I wanted to know how not to pass it to /private/tmp, just run it from within the Resources folder of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite similar, just omit the copying part

```
set myPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to resource "MyComandLineTool"))
do shell script myPath & " -r" with administrator privileges
```

Note: `quoted form of` is always good practice as the path could contain space characters

Comment: Thanks for your help.